# Got Laravel 5 installed but blade and routing not working correctly, what to do?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-routing

Have been stuck for 2 days now and I've extensively researched the internet but can't get this thing to work. I've installed laravel 5 using composer, followed a few tutorials but for some reason when I create new views, it reroutes to my public folder instead of the views folder.
install directory: 
c:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\
I enabled the overwrite all in http.conf
my root directory is set to:
"C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname/public"

when i type localhost in my browser the welcome.blade.php loads and displays correctly. 
I've created a new controller:

```
<?php
class authors extends Controller{   
public $restful=true;
public function get_index(){
        // return view::make('authors.index');
        $view= view::make('authors.index',array('name'=>'My Name'))->with ('email','28');
        $view->location='amsterdam';
        return $view;
}}
```

routes.php looks as follows:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'authors@index'));
```

inside views I created a folder called authors and inside that folder i placed index.blade.php:

test

now when I try to find localhost/authors it should redirect to subfolder authors and open index.blade.php, but i get:

```
Index of /authors

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -    
[TXT]   index.blade.php 2015-08-04 07:46    209  
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11 Server at localhost Port 80
```

I can direct to the public folder and call index.php there, but the blade template doesn't work there and I can't recall the date from $view that i put in (such as $name, $email, etc.). 
I checked the folder permissions and ensured that the folder permissions were set correctly. I also tried the following things:
- reinstall laravel (didnt work) 
- started with WAMP and switched to XAMP (didnt work)

I just started using Laravel as it looks really user friendly and time saving as i was getting a bit fed up with sql queries and i needed a solid framework for password protection. I've got my website ready using html, css and php. Now the last step is implementing laravel to improve future functionality and stability. 
I'm really stuck here, please help me out so I can finish my website and get it online in a safe way

Answer (score 0):

Not all too familiar with laravel since I've been using it for a couple of days. Maybe try the following below instead of making an array?

```
Route::get('authors','authors@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable mod_rewrite in your apache config. Open httpd.conf (or apache2.conf, it depends on your Apache Install) and uncomment the line which starts with "LoadModule rewrite_module".

Answer (score 0):

did have mod_rewrite enabled already in the config. One of my buddies walked in and helped me out. looks like i used some old Laravel 4 code in Laravel5.

Renamed controller to: AuthorController, changed the function to index and removed public $restful=true.
changed route to:

```
Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'AuthorController@index'));
```

initially i had put a page in the public folder. the .htaccess looks as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

which basically redirected me to index.php

hopefully this will be useful for others, thanks for taking the time to respond